# How to store a textfield without containing blanks in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I enter the field IBAN with length 27 as

xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx

in my view.

The IBAN field in the database has length 22.

How can I cut off the blanks that I get from the view, before the field is stored to the database ?

Peter

Comment: use `yourString.trim()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is in the controller. 
You can replace the blank spaces using the Java String replaceAll() Method.

Example:

```
  String replaceString=s1.replaceAll(" ","");//replaces all blanks spaces
```

Documentation:

replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html